# How to enable cmdlet parameter auto-complete popup on PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, windows-10, powershell-5.0, powershell-v5.1

So I'm following this beginner PowerShell tutorial [here](https://blog.netwrix.com/2018/02/21/windows-powershell-scripting-tutorial-for-beginners/) and am following the bit that shows how to enable the auto-suggestion popup that comes up when trying to see all possible parameters for a particular cmdlet. So when I try to replicate it by typing '-' after a cmdlet, according to the article, a popup should come up showing all possible parameters for the cmdlet. But for me this doesn't seem to work- although it does appear in a particular format, but only after I type ctrl+space.

Is there a way to have the parameters come up automatically **and** in a popup format?

So here is how the article shows auto suggestions popup:

[image]

And here is my PowerShell where I have to enter ctrl+space but the parameters appear in different format:

[image]

N.B. I am using PowerShell 5.1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the article you linked:

> Each cmdlet has several parameters that customize what it does. **The PowerShell ISE** will automatically suggest all valid parameters and their types after you type a cmdlet and a hyphen (-)

PowerShell ISE is the "Integrated Scripting Environment" development tool for powershell that ships with Windows.

`powershell.exe` is *not* PowerShell ISE.

To launch ISE, either type `ise` and hit enter from the powershell prompt, or open the Run menu, and launch `powershell_ise.exe`

Comment: Oh wow, did not even notice that- thought it was the same thing. Thanks a lot!